# How can I 'refresh' a 'helper' function in Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Sometimes I need to refresh the "helper" functions.

An example:
if the the database connection function is in a helper function, and the database access changed, and I store this access data in a sqlite database, and I overwrite this data (in the sqlite database), how can I refresh in this situation the helper function?

Comment: Explain what is database access and do you use another db in addition to sqlite.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to query the sqlite database for changes every time you connect or reuse the handle to your main database. If you notice a change in sqlite, you need to disconnect from the main, pull new credentials and reconnect to the main using new credentials.

```
$app->helper(
    db => sub {
      my $self = shift;
      my $credentials_changed = your_function_to_check_this(...);
      if($credentials_changed){
        $dbh->disconnect if $dbh;
        return db_connect(
          $credentials->{db_host},     $credentials->{db_user},
          $credentials->{db_database}, $credentials->{db_pass}
       );
    }
);

sub db_connect {
  my ($db_host, $db_user, $db_database, $db_pass) = @_;
  my $dbh = 0;
  $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$db_database;host=$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_pass", {'RaiseError' => 1});
  $dbh->{mysql_auto_reconnect} = 1;
  return $dbh;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that `has` is an attribute and thus the code block is only run the first time. If that were a helper rather than an attribute it would work as you describe.

Comment: Woah, that means that my connection to DB is super stable and it doesn't break for days :) I will correct the answer and implement it as a helper.